# How to show percentages in org-tables?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

Consider the following table:

```
|--------+------|
| Number |    % |
|--------+------|
|  0.004 | 0.40 |
| 0.0047 | 0.47 |
|   0.01 | 1.00 |
|  0.019 | 1.90 |
|--------+------|
#+TBLFM: $2=$1*100; %.2f
```

How could I change $2 formula so it would look like this:

```
|--------+-------|
| Number |     % |
|--------+-------|
|  0.004 | 0.40% |
| 0.0047 | 0.47% |
|   0.01 | 1.00% |
|  0.019 | 1.90% |
|--------+-------|
```

Comment: Note that you probably don't want to do that on any column that is going to be used as input to another calculation: prettify output columns only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add arbitrary text after the formatting.  To get a `%` you need to double the symbol

```
|--------+-------|
| Number |     % |
|--------+-------|
|  0.004 | 0.40% |
| 0.0047 | 0.47% |
|   0.01 | 1.00% |
|  0.019 | 1.90% |
|--------+-------|
#+TBLFM: $2=$1*100; %.2f%%
```